# .NET custom route overwrites normal

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, url, routes

This is my custom route

```
// custom route
routes.MapRoute(
    "Custom",
    "Town/{townName}/{restaurantID}",
    new { controller = "Town", action = "View", restaurantID = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Problem is when I click on `Create` action URL is (as it should be) `Town/Create` but site recognizes `Create` as `townName` which is problem... Same thing is happening with `Edit`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you are dealing with 2 very generic routes. Whichever is ordered first would have precedence, but neither ordering would satisfy what you want. The easiest way to fix this is use a constraint or to specify additional routes for Create and Edit.

Here is what it would look like to create additional routes to make Create and Edit explicit.

**Note:** Keep in mind that with this URL structure you can never have a town named "Edit" or "Create". Fortunately, these towns do not seem to exist on the earth (yet), but there is the town of Délété to worry about: http://nona.net/features/map/placedetail.2381031/D%C3%A9l%C3%A9t%C3%A9/

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Town_Edit",
    "Town/Edit/{restaurantID}",
    new { controller = "Town", action = "Edit" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Town_Create",
    "Town/Create/",
    new { controller = "Town", action = "Create" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Town",
    "Town/{townName}/{restaurantID}",
    new { controller = "Town", action = "View", restaurantID = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

// Default route here
```

Comment: Just question: can you write also constraint version?

Comment: Got it:                 new { townName = "((?!^Create|Edit$)(^.*$))" } //Restriction for "Create" and "Edit" townName